# Durbin-Watson Statistics interpretation from Cochrane-Orcutt estimation

Tags: r, regression, p-value, panel-data, durbin-watson-test

When I run the `cochrane.orcutt()` command from the package `orcutt` over my panel regression to reduce the autocorrelation problem, I get the following message:

```
 Durbin-Watson statistic 
 (original):    NA , p-value: NA
 (transformed): 2.07320 , p-value: 7.295e-01
```

It shows that the transformed method that I used gives out 2.07320 Durbin-Watson statistics value with p-value of 7.295e-01 if I am correct. Does this mean that I am safe from autocorrelation problem? I am a bit confused because normally the Durbin-Watson test value of around 2 is accompanied by insignificant p-value which should be quite high I suppose. May I ask help on this interpretation?

Comment: Thank you but this is directly coming from r code called 'cochrane.orcutt() from 'orcutt' package.

Comment: The function `cochrane.orcutt()` requires "a linear model built with lm function" as the documentation states. As you say you applied it to a panel regression - likely an object created by `plm()` or `lfe()` -, I don't now if the function produces sane output for those.